# c client sending char but server is receiving a number

Tags: c, server, client

for an assignment we are required to make a game with client-server functionality. Currently I am trying to send a single character from the client to the server which is associated with an option. In this case I am sending the character 'Q' which is input by the player using the scanf() function. When input the client is correctly reading the char as a 'Q' but when sent to the server, it is read as 20736 which I'm guessing is the ascii code for the letter Q.

This is extra strange because I send a bunch of characters from the server to client earlier in the code using the same method and it is recieved as a char just fine. Any idea why this is happening in one case and not the other? This is my first experience with using C so there's probably something simple I'm missing.

Below is the code from the client and server where the client is sending an input from the client to the server. Currently the server just prints the received character to see if its working correctly. The GameBoard and GameState types are structs that have a 2d array of chars called tiles, aswell as some other variables.

The printf("%c", receiveString) is printing 20736 in the first server code snippet, when the client is sending the char type variable 'optionSelected' which has the value 'Q' which as been input by the user. It should be printing a 'Q'. It is also returning false in if statements 'if (receiveString == 'Q').

client:

```
void playGame(int sockfd) {
    int remainingMines = 10, gameOver = 0;
    char optionSelected;
    gameBoard board = receiveBoardState(sockfd);

    while(gameOver == 0) {
        printf("\n\n\nRemaining mines: %d \n\n", remainingMines);
        displayBoard(board);

        printf("\n\nChoose an option: \n<R> Reveal tile\n<P> Place flag\n<Q> Quit game \n\n Option (R, P, Q):");
        scanf("%c", &optionSelected);
        send(sockfd, &optionSelected, sizeof(char), 0);
        if (optionSelected == 'Q') {
            gameOver = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
void playGame(int new_fd) {
    char receiveString;
    int numbytes, gameOver = 0;
    GameState game = constructGamestate();
    sendBoard(game, new_fd);

    if ((numbytes=recv(new_fd, &receiveString, sizeof(char), 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%c", receiveString);    
}
```

Also here are the snippets of code where the client is correctly receiving and printing a char that was sent to it from the server.

Client:

```
gameBoard receiveBoardState(int sockfd) {

    gameBoard board;
    char receiveData;
    int numbytes;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TILES_X; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < NUM_TILES_Y; j++) {
            if ((numbytes=recv(sockfd, &receiveData, sizeof(char), 0)) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            } else board.tiles[i][j] = receiveData;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

Server:

```
void sendBoard(GameState game,int new_fd) {
    char * uiElements = "ABCDEFGHI";
    char sendChar;
    printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
    printf("---------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = -1; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j == -1) {
                printf("\n%c |",uiElements[i]);
            } else {
                sendChar = (game.tiles[i][j].adjacent_mines + '0');
                if (game.tiles[i][j].is_mine == true)
                    sendChar = '*';
                printf(" %c", sendChar);
                send(new_fd, &sendChar, sizeof(char), 0);
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is read as 20736" ? How did you conclude that ? Which part of the code is not behaving as you expect ? How is it behaving ? How did you expect it to behave ?

Comment: My bad I guess I wasn't clear enough, the printf("%c", &receiveString) is printing 20736 in the first server code snippet, when the client is sending the char type variable  'optionSelected' which has the value 'Q' which as been input by the user. It should be printing a 'Q'. It is also returning true in if statements 'if (receiveString == 20736)' and returning false in if statements 'if (receiveString == 'Q').

Comment: Be sure to use `printf("%c", receiveString)` - _not_ `printf("%c", &receiveString)`. I.e. `printf()` expects the _value_ of `receiveString` - not its address.

Comment: @david I have already tried that but on compile it gives me an error if I'm not pointing to the address. edit: wait sorry I misread that, that was a mistype in the comment and question, you can see in the code I don't print &receiveString, but just receiveString and still encounter the issue.

Comment: The ASCII code for 'Q' is 81. (ASCII codes are always between 0 and 255.) A good starting point would be to use a debugger and place a breakpoint after `recv()`. Then examine the values of both `numbytes` and `receiveString` explicitly. It's possible `recv()` is returning `0` - which you are not checking for in your code.

Comment: A single character can never hold the value 20736. And even if it would hold that value, `printf("%c");` would print a single character.

Comment: Thanks david, printing the value of numbytes it prints 1, will the values be different for numbytes and receiveString from what they are actually printing if I use a debugger? If not, then recv() does not seem to be returning 0. Its also worth noting that sending the server letters other than 'Q' will print different numbers.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I can upload screenshots of the output to the question if you'd like, but I can assure you that it is printing '20736' for Q, and other 5 digit numbers for other letters. You're right about char not being able to contain this value though, because I cannot compare receiveString to 20736 or '20736' without getting a compile error.

Comment: There is no use for a screenshot if you can copy&paste text. Did you verify that the "20736" is printed in one call to `printf`? You might call your function multiple times and only print 1 digit at a time? To verify you could change format string to `"%c "`.

Comment: I have verfied that 20736 is printed in a single printf call, because I have changed it to "%c \n" while trying to fix the issue, still prints 20736 on a single line.

Comment: How did you call `playGame` function at your server side ? Did you put that function in a loop ? And since you use client - server pattern, how many clients are connecting to your server ? Maybe you have multiple clients, and `playGame` function at your server side get called more than once, so you have more than one character get printed on the screen ? Did you use blocking IO or non-blocking IO ? Like other people said, it's impossible for `print("%c", receivedChar);` to print a number like 20736.

Answer (score 0):

The server cannot read 20736, as a `char` can only have values 0 to 255 or -128 to 127. A `char` can be signed or unsigned, the c standard allows both. If you require an unsigned one, you must write `unsigned char` and if you require a signed one, you must write `signed char`; if you just write `char`, you leave it up to the compiler to decide that for you. But all the widespread platforms today define a char to be one byte and a byte has 8 bits on all modern platforms and thus a single byte can for sure never be 20736.

Could the problem be, that you are printing multiple numbers? As `printf` will not add a space after output or a new line. So this code

```
prinft("10");
prinft("20");
prinft("30");
```

will actually print

```
102030
```